# Proof Using Archimedean Property

Tags: analysis

An exercise from my book is as follows:

Assume that $x > 0$ for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (Real numbers) then there is an $y$ in $\mathbb{N}$ (Natural Numbers) such that $1/y^3 < x$.

By the archimedean property, there exists an y in N such that $1/y < x$. How exactly would I continue on from here?

Comment: $y^3>y$. no!...

Comment: Have you proven that for any positive real x and any natural n that there exists a real y so that y^n =x?  If not, prove it with s= sup {y|y^n < x}.  You can prove that s^n=y.  It's a bit of a pain but can be done.

Comment: Oh, never mind my comment.  I misread.

Comment: 0 <1/y < 1.  So 1/y.1/y . 1/y < 1 . 1/y.1/y <1.1.1/y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Archimedean property there exists a natural number $y$ such that $xy >1$. Then $xy^3 >xy >1$.  So $1/(y^3) <x$.

Answer (score 1):

The indirect way is to remember for $a>0$ and $s <t $ we have $as < at $.

So if $y > 1$ then $ \frac 1 y < 1$ and $1/y^3 = 1/y*1/y^2=1/y*1/y*1/y$.  And $1/y > 0$.

So if you know $1/y <x$ what can you say about $1/y^3$ and $x $? What can you say about $1/y^3$ and $1/y $?

Comment: In your first line, if $a>0$ and $s<t$, then should it be $sa<at$? Yours is $sa<st$.

Comment: Yep.  That's exactly what it should be.